# ng-show not working for dynamically added HTML within my controller

Tags: angularjs

[Please see relevant JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/450/)

Within this code I dynamically added in sanitized HTML code using ng-bind-html but when assigning ng-show to the html it does not work. I tried using $compile but so far nothing as well.

I am trying to hide and show an element using ng-show but both are visible.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngSanitize'])

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {

  $scope.myHTML = [];  

  $scope.myHTML.push('<li ng-show = "visible(1)">Test1</li>');  
  $scope.myHTML.push('<li ng-show = "visible(0)>Test2</li>');  

 $scope.visible = function(arg)
 {
  if (arg == 1) return true;  
  if (arg == 0) return false;  

 }

  $compile($scope.myHTML)($scope);

});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="snippet in myHTML" ng-bind-html="snippet"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller should pretty much never be aware of markup, ever. That's the power of MVC. You should repeat across a real dataset and build up markup in your view. Something like the following, where you set `items = [item1, item2]` in a controller.

```
<div ng-app="HelloApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul ng-repeat="item in items">
           <li ng-show = "test($index)">Test{{$index}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you really need to do it the way you're doing, you should use a custom directive and use `angular.element` to append your compiled html to the current directive element. ng-bind-html doesn't expect a compiled node, rather just an html string.

Comment: Well I'm actually using a directive so I cannot do this.

My real code is like:
 template: '<ul ng-repeat="snippet in myHTML" ng-bind-html="snippet"></ul>'. Since the amount of items added can be variable.

Comment: Why can't your directive template have the repeated `li` in it? See my edit, if you really need to do it the way you want, you need `angular.elements`'s ,  append method. The only valid use of ng-bind-html is if the html is defined in the database, and is unique per item eg using tinymce for use defined html. However, your question implies each item has the same template, and thus should be defined in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not true. 
First , your `ng-repeat` is in `ul`, `scope.myHTML` will loop `ul` instead of adding DOM in `ul`, so you should `ng-repeat` in `li`.  code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="snippet in myHTML" ng-bind-html="snippet" ng-show="snippet.visible">{{ snippet.content }}</li>
</ul>
```

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.myHTML = [{content:'Test1', visible:1},{content:'Test2', visible:0}];
    $scope.visible = function(arg)
    {
        if (arg == 1) return true;
        if (arg == 0) return false;
    }
});
```

Maybe, you want to just add DOM like jQuery. code like this:

```
<ul>
</ul>
```

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.visible = function(arg)
    {
        if (arg == 1) return true;
        if (arg == 0) return false;
    }
    $('ul').html($compile('<li ng-show="visible(1)">Test1</li><li ng-show="visible(0)">Test2</li>')($scope));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i used `$timeout` function it's working with me : sample code

```
$scope.allowDelete = false;
$scope.allowDeleteCount = '';

$timeout(function () {
   $('div').append($compile('<button type="button" ng-show="allowDelete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete <span>{{allowDeleteCount}}<span></button>')($scope))
},1000);
```